# undefined local variable or method 'get'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

I take out the accents and i have this error

I run RoR 3.2.0.rc1,  Ruby 1.9.2 and i work one Ubuntu 11.10

> Showing /home/rene/ruby_dev/ch05/txt2fields/app/views/look/input.html where line #13 raised:
>
> undefined local variable or method `get' for #<#:0x9557f04>
>
> Extracted source (around line #13):

```
10:             <br>
11:             Elle transmet la variable au modele.
12:             <br>
13:             <%= text_form_tag :action => 'at', :method => get %>
14:             Votre nom.
15:             <br>
16:             <%= text_field_tag  'text1',  nil, :size => 30 %>
```

PS I change "post" with "get" and i have a same problem9

Comment: IMO if the answer works, it should be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a symbol here.

```
<%= text_form_tag :action => 'at', :method => :get %>
                                              ^ 
                                              |  this is important
```

`get` is interpreted as a variable name, and such variable doesn't exist in the scope. Hence the error.

Comment: Notice the colon in front of `:get`?